# AttributeError: This QueryDict instance is immutable

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework, django-views

The issue is that when i try to post data on my end point its throwing error in customer serializer but not in merchant serializer im taking id from json web token and so thats why im overriding and not taking customer_id but assigning it in isvalid

Error is

```
Internal Server Error: /users/customer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Envs\cashless\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Envs\cashless\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Envs\cashless\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Envs\cashless\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 104, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Envs\cashless\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Envs\cashless\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Envs\cashless\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Envs\cashless\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Envs\cashless\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Desktop\Cashless\Users\api\views.py", line 64, in customer_register
    if serializer.is_valid():
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Desktop\Cashless\Users\api\serializers.py", line 71, in is_valid
    self.initial_data['customer_id'] = request.user.id
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Envs\cashless\lib\site-packages\django\http\request.py", line 555, in __setitem__
    self._assert_mutable()
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah\Envs\cashless\lib\site-packages\django\http\request.py", line 552, in _assert_mutable
    raise AttributeError("This QueryDict instance is immutable")
AttributeError: This QueryDict instance is immutable
```

Serializer.py is

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    customer= CustomUserSerializer(read_only=True)
    customer_id=serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model=Customer
        fields='__all__'
    
    def is_valid(self, *, raise_exception=False):
        request=self.context['request']        
        self.initial_data['customer_id'] = request.user.id
        valid=super().is_valid(raise_exception=raise_exception)
        return valid

class MerchantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    merchant= CustomUserSerializer(read_only=True)
    merchant_id=serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model=Merchant
        fields='__all__'

    def is_valid(self, *, raise_exception=False):
        request=self.context['request']
        self.initial_data['merchant_id'] = request.user.id
        valid=super().is_valid(raise_exception=raise_exception)
        return valid
```

Models.py

```
class Merchant(models.Model):
    
    merchant=models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, related_name='owner',primary_key=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo=models.ImageField()
    CNIC= models.CharField(max_length=13,validators=[MinLengthValidator(13)],unique=True,null=False,blank=False)
    NTN=models.CharField(max_length=13,null=False,blank=False)
    address=models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    account_title=models.CharField(max_length=30,null=False,blank=False)
    IBFT=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=False,blank=False)
    account_no=models.CharField(max_length=24,null=False,blank=False)
    bankname= models.ForeignKey(Bank, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_verified=models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.merchant}'
class CardType(models.Model):
    cardtype=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=False,blank=False)

class Customer(models.Model):
    customer=models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,verbose_name=_('Customer Name'),on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    card_number=models.CharField(_('Card Number'),max_length=16,null=False,blank=False)
    card_type=models.ForeignKey(CardType,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    expiry_date= CardExpiryField(_('expiration date'),null=False,blank=False)
    name_card=models.CharField(_('Card Name'),max_length=30,null=False,blank=False)
    cvc=models.CharField(_('CVC'),max_length=3,null=False,blank=False)
    bankname= models.ForeignKey(Bank,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    account_no=models.CharField(_('Account Number'),max_length=24,null=False,blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.customer}'
```

Views.py is

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def merchant_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = MerchantSerializer(data=request.data,context={'request': request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            data={}
            user=serializer.save()
            user=CustomUser.objects.get(id=user.merchant_id)
            refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
            data['refresh_token']= str(refresh)
            data['access_token']=str(refresh.access_token)
            data['user_id']=user.id 
            data['merchant_type'] = user.is_merchant
            data['customer_type'] = user.is_customer
            return Response(data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
    merchant=Merchant.objects.all()
    serializer=MerchantSerializer(merchant,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def customer_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = CustomerSerializer(data=request.data,context={'request':request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            data={}
            user=serializer.save()
            user=CustomUser.objects.get(id=user.customer_id)
            refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
            data['refresh_token']= str(refresh)
            data['access_token']=str(refresh.access_token)
            data['user_id']=user.id 
            data['merchant_type'] = user.is_merchant
            data['customer_type'] = user.is_customer
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
    customer=Customer.objects.all()
    serializer=CustomerSerializer(customer,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I tried different ai tools but can't come up with any solution

Comment: `self.initial_data['merchant_id'] = request.user.id` makes no sense: the initial data can not be modified easily, and should not anyway.

Comment: so how can i add merchant_id from jwt without taking it in json ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

omit the field in the serializer:

```
class MerchantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    merchant = CustomUserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Merchant
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['merchant']
```

in the view we then save the item with the `merchant_id`:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def merchant_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = MerchantSerializer(
            data=request.data, context={'request': request}
        )
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save(merchant_id=request.user.pk)
            user = CustomUser.objects.get(id=user.merchant_id)
            refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
            data['refresh_token'] = str(refresh)
            data['access_token'] = str(refresh.access_token)
            data['user_id'] = user.id
            data['merchant_type'] = user.is_merchant
            data['customer_type'] = user.is_customer
            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
    merchant = Merchant.objects.all()
    serializer = MerchantSerializer(merchant, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

---

> **Note**: Using a custom view is often not a good idea, since for several views you will need to write similar code, and thus implement boilerplate logic. It is therefore often better to subclass a [**`ModelViewSet`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset), and override some of the methods to (slightly) alter the behavior.

Comment: and same goes for customer ??? because the problem was in customer

Comment: @AbdullahMoudood: yes, you do the same for the customer.